# Calculated date value format is 2020-02-02T22:00:00Z instead of local time format

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, date, format

I'm a beginner with SharePoint so I hope you won't find my question too strange. I am facing a problem that I can't solve alone.

Here is the problem:
I ha ve made a list with a specific column called "Date de Conditionnement" and two other column are calculated from that one using a calculated field [Date de Conditionnement]+5. Everithyng was working fine with a local format of date. Since a few days the calculated fields appears as 2020-02-02T22:00:00Z i.e. in ISO8601 format but the non calculated fields appears normaly.
I was working on JSON formating of other field of that specific list when it happened.
This problem is limited to this list and does not appears in classical SharePoint view. Does anyone has a solution to get back to normal?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `toLocaleString()` to convert the datetime string.

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "=toLocaleString(@currentField)"
}
```